# How to handle python json dump if separator also present in json value

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am using json dump in python with separtors like below:

```
json.dump(data, outputfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
```

But my data has few key value pairs in which itemseparator ',' is also present. I do not want to treat that as itemseparator

For example:
*{"withComma" : "1,23"}*
This should be treated as
*"withComma": ["1,23"]* and NOT as *"withComma":["1","23"]*

Comment: That should work fine. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2):

`separators` does not affect the formatting of strings, only the formatting of objects.
As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) describes

> If specified, separators should be an (item_separator, key_separator) tuple. By default, (', ', ': ') are used. To get the most compact JSON representation, you should specify (',', ':') to eliminate whitespace.

You can easily see this with some examples.  Note the extra spaces around the `:` in the second case

```
$ python -c 'import json; print json.dumps({"withComma":"1,23"})'
{"withComma": "1,23"}

$ python -c 'import json; print json.dumps({"withComma":"1,23"}, separators=(" , ", " : "))'
{"withComma" : "1,23"}
```

If you require string values like `"1,23"` to be converted to array values like `["1,23"]` or `["1", "23"]` you're going to need to do that on your own before calling `json.dump`